# How to center logo while having no action bar menu

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, toolbar

I'm hidding my action bar base on some condition. But when it's hided, the logo inside my toolbar is not center.

How can I fix that ?

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/bleuClair"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/colorBlack"
        app:titleMarginStart="0dp">
        <ImageView
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_hd"
            android:contentDescription="@string/remi_logo_desc" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This way -

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/bleuClair"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/colorBlack"
    app:titleMarginStart="0dp">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_hd"
        android:contentDescription="@string/remi_logo_desc" />

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks ! So easy, and I needed also to change width of my image

Answer (score 0):

Adding one extra LinearLayout with android:gravity="center" should help:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/bleuClair"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/colorBlack"
        app:titleMarginStart="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_hd"
            android:contentDescription="@string/remi_logo_desc" />

    </LinearLayout>


 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```